# How do I get a list of the user's contacts in iOS 6?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios6

I have been using the following code for a few years now and it has always worked, but it looks like with iOS 6 it doesn't anymore. How do I get a list of all contacts on an iOS 6 device?

```
ABAddressBookRef myAddressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
        NSMutableArray *people = (__bridge_transfer NSMutableArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(myAddressBook);
        CFRelease(myAddressBook);

        // repeat through all contacts in the inital array we loaded
        for(int i=0; i<[people count]; i++)
        {
            NSString *aName;
            NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)([people objectAtIndex:i]), kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
            NSString *lastName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)([people objectAtIndex:i]), kABPersonLastNameProperty);

            if (([firstName isEqualToString:@""] || [firstName isEqualToString:@"(null)"] || firstName == nil) &&
                ([lastName isEqualToString:@""] || [lastName isEqualToString:@"(null)"] || lastName == nil))
            {
                // do nothing
            }
            else 
            {
                aName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];

                if ([firstName isEqualToString:@""] || [firstName isEqualToString:@"(null)"] || firstName == nil)
                {
                    aName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", lastName];
                }

                if ([lastName isEqualToString:@""] || [lastName isEqualToString:@"(null)"] || lastName == nil)
                {
                    aName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", firstName];
                }

                [self.tableItems addObject:aName];
            }

        }

        [self.tableItems sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Comment: I think that code WILL still work, as long as you grant contacts permission for your app...

Comment: well, presumably this is wanted for use in an app on other end user devices and forcing them to manually give permission probably won't happen unless they get prompted for it... so requesting it should be part of the implementation for an iOS 6 app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ios6 you need to ask for permission to read the AddressBook, otherwise you'll get nil. Use something like this:

```
- (BOOL)askContactsPermission {
    __block BOOL ret = NO;
    if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion != NULL) { // we're on iOS6

        dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            ret = granted;
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
        });
        if (addressBook) {
            CFRelease(addressBook);
        }

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        dispatch_release(sema);
    }
    else { // we're on iOS5 or older
        ret = YES;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

If this method returns NO, bad luck, you won't be able to access the AB. I'm locking with a semaphore here because I don't want to continue with my app if the user does not allow the AB. There other methods, just check the API.

Comment: Perfect Solution, But It did not ask user permission to access the Addressbook so is this Correct way to get Users Data?

Answer (score 4):

You do need to ask the user for permission which will trigger a prompt to the user when you do so. Here's another way to do this using execution blocks to handle the result, also makes the usage of it version agnostic if you need to query your current access status from common code.

I implement an access manager like so

AppContactsAccessManager.h

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>

typedef enum
{
    kABAuthStatusNotDetermined = 0,
    kABAuthStatusRestricted,
    kABAuthStatusDenied,
    kABAuthStatusAuthorized,
    kABAuthStatusPending,
}AddressBookAuthStatus;

typedef void (^AddressbookRequestHandler)(ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef, BOOL available);

@interface AppContactsAccessManager : NSObject
{
     AddressBookAuthStatus status;
}
- (void) requestAddressBookWithCompletionHandler:(AddressbookRequestHandler)handler;
- (AddressBookAuthStatus) addressBookAuthLevel;

@end
```

AppContactsAccessManager.m

```
@implementation AppContactsAccessManager

- (BOOL) isStatusAvailable:(AddressBookAuthStatus)theStatus
{
    return (theStatus == kABAuthStatusAuthorized || theStatus == kABAuthStatusRestricted);
}

- (void) requestAddressBookWithCompletionHandler:(AddressbookRequestHandler)handler
{
    ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = NULL;

    if([self isiOS6]){
        addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil);
        ABAuthorizationStatus curStatus = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus();
        if(curStatus == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
        {
            status = kABAuthStatusPending;
            ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
                status = ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus();
                if(handler != NULL){
                    handler(addressBookRef, [self isStatusAvailable:status]);
                }
            });
        }else
        {
            status = curStatus;
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
                if(handler != NULL){
                    handler(addressBookRef, [self isStatusAvailable:status]);
                }
            });
        }
    }else
    {
        addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreate();
        status = kABAuthStatusAuthorized;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
            if(handler != NULL){
                handler(addressBookRef, [self isStatusAvailable:status]);
            }
            });
        }
}

- (AddressBookAuthStatus) addressBookAuthLevel
{
        return status;
}

@end
```

usage would look something like:

```
AppContactsAccessManager* accessMgr = [AppContactsAccessManager new];
[accessMgr requestAddressBookWithCompletionHandler:^(ABAddressBookRef theAddressBookRef, BOOL available) {
    // do your addressbook stuff in here
}];
```

Comment: dispatch_get_current_queue is deprecated